# Are these two conditions equivalent (in a sql)?

Tags: sql, logic

There is a condition in our sql

```
and (A is null or (A is not null and B is null))
```

I think it is equivalent with

```
and (A is null or B is null)
```

And I checked it with all combination items (A is null, B is null...). It seems that they are equivalent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two expressions are indeed identical.

```
A is null or (A is not null and B is null)
```

If `A is null` is false, then it means that `A is not null` is necessarily true. That's the principle of `IS` and `IS NOT`. In other words, in expression `A is null or (A is not null and B is null)`, the part that says `A is not null` is redundant : we know already that this is the case, as the first condition of the expression, `A is null` was not fullfilled.

Hence, you should use the second form, whose syntax is not redudant, and might even perform better, depending on how smart your RDBMS is :

```
and (A is null or B is null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the simple answer is they produce the same result set.

Both conditions are *equivalent* but not *equal*. Read on.

Keep in mind that different databases have better or worse optimizers. Since SQL is a declarative language, some optimizers will be able to simplify or *rewrite* the SQL condition and take advantage of some indexes, while other dummier optimizers won't.

In sum, you could see *some* differences when using one condition or the other. Particularly:

- Higher/Lower performance. Some databases will be able to produce a better [smarter] execution plan that will be faster and/or less resource intensive.
- Different row orders. Depending on the execution plan, in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, some databases will walk the table heaps in different orders or using different indexes, and you'll get the same rows in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

They are and you can also use ((A + B) is null) which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic logic.  You can check this with a truth table:

```
A        B        expr1      expr2
NULL     NULL     TRUE       TRUE
NULL     not      TRUE       TRUE
not      NULL     TRUE       TRUE
not      not      FALSE      FALSE
```

Hence, they are equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it in this way. But I don't if there are traps.

Comment: They may be equivalent logically. But semantically it's not. I stand on the table. Table is on the floor. Therefore I am above the floor

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . What is that supposed to mean?  Do you know what "semantics" means?  It means they are logically equivalent statements; they are **semantically** the same.

Comment: I would use the "simplified" second option over the first because it's more clear.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . Presumably, that is why the OP is asking the question.